# dplyr rename "object not found"

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

When I try and rename multiple columns in dplyr, I'm getting an "object not found" error regarding the new name.

I am creating a new data frame using select, and then I'd like to change the names of columns 4:8.

```
commute_mode<-select(commute,geoid,GEO.id2,display_label,HD01_VD26,HD01_VD37,HD01_VD68,HD01_VD113,HD01_VD125) %>%
  rename(HD01_VD26 = drive, HD01_VD37 = carpool,HD01_VD68 = public_trans,HD01_VD113 = walk, HD01_VD125=bike_other)
```

but I'm getting

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'drive' not found
```

Comment: Swap the order for renaming, It's new name = current. `drive = HD01_VD26`

Comment: You need to put `drive = HD01_VD26` not `HD01_VD26 = drive`. It's also redundant to call `rename` here, you can simply rename the variables inside `select`.

Comment: I'm commenting here because the question has been closed, but this error frequently occurs when you have multiple packages loaded that have a different `rename` function; using the `dplyr::rename` function fixes the cryptic error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been pointed out in some comments, the new and old names of the variables need to be swapped in your `select()` function.

But as has also been noted, you can select AND rename your variables using `select()` by itself (`rename()` is best if you are keeping all the columns and only renaming certain ones). So instead of the unwieldy `mydata %>% select(old_var1, old_var2) %>% rename (new_var1 = old_var1, new_var2 = old_var2)`, you simply have `mydata %>% select(new_var1 = old_var1, new_var2 = old_var2)`. In your case, this would look like:

```
commute_mode <- commute %>% select(geoid, GEO.id2, display_label,
                                   drive = HD01_VD26, carpool = HD01_VD37,
                                   public_trans = HD01_VD68,
                                   walk = HD01_VD113,
                                   bike_other = HD01_VD125)
```

This is a great feature of the `select()` command, and it's always best to keep things as concise as possible!

For a more detailed explanation, you can check out https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html